# WiX burn: how to change 'WixBundleManufacturer' in bootstrapper application?

Tags: c#, wix, bootstrapper, burn

I am building a customizable setup application with WiX, having started with this tutorial:
http://bryanpjohnston.com/2012/09/28/custom-wix-managed-bootstrapper-application/

The setup needs to be customizable, so I need to set some Variables from inside my `MainViewModel` this is an example:

```
var customProductName = "The Custom Product";
this.Bootstrapper.Engine.StringVariables["WixBundleName"] = theCustomProduct;
```

This works how expected. However, I cannot set the Variable `WixBundleManufacturer`. I get a `System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range`.

Is it somehow possible to set the manufacturer value from inside my view model at runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [feature request](http://wixtoolset.org/issues/3933/) was implemented in v3.10.0.1719.  The variable is now writable like any other Burn variable.

Answer (score 3):

No, the WixBundleManufacturer is read-only variable set from the authored `Bundle` element `Manufacturer` attribute. You could open a feature request.